# How to treat database row results and list slicers as strings in order to get Levenshtein function to work properly

Tags: python

I am stuck so please help me.  My objective is to compute the Levenshtein distance between each description in my database and the description in the following row.  I am getting close but I believe the following line...

```
x = editdistance.eval(item, t[a:b])
```

... is not working because item and t[a:b] are not being treated as strings.

How can I convert them to strings so it will work?

Code:

```
import csv
import sqlite3
from array import *
import editdistance
conn = sqlite3.connect('transactions.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select distinct description from transactions order by description')
t=[]
for row in c:
    row = c.fetchone()
    t.append(row)
for item in t:
    if t.index(item)<10: #just to limit output for testing
        print item
        a = t.index(item)+1
        b = a + 1
        print t[a:b]
        x = editdistance.eval(item, t[a:b])
        print x
        print "\n"
```

Output:

(u'STARBUCKS #02472 LOUIS Louisville KY Debit Card Withdrawal: M/C DEBIT CARD',)
[(u'STARBUCKS #21137 LOUIS Louisville KY Debit Card Withdrawal: M/C DEBIT CARD',)]

1

(u'STARBUCKS #21137 LOUIS Louisville KY Debit Card Withdrawal: M/C DEBIT CARD',)
[(u'STARBUCKS STORE 02561 LOUISVILLE KY Debit Card Withdrawal: M/C DEBIT CARD',)]

1

(u'STARBUCKS STORE 02561 LOUISVILLE KY Debit Card Withdrawal: M/C DEBIT CARD',)
[(u'STEAK-N-SHAKE#0701 LOUISVILLE KY Debit Card Withdrawal: M/C DEBIT CARD',)]

1

Comment: Nevermind I am an idiot.  For some reason it didn't work before but now works when I simply do x = editdistance.eval(str(item), str(t[a:b]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I am an idiot. For some reason it didn't work before but now works when I simply do x = editdistance.eval(str(item), str(t[a:b]))